# Gui Development with Python and PyQt5, is it possible to use a variable to get to control a widget?

Tags: python, user-interface

I've been looking a long time for this problem, I still don't know if it is even possible.
I would like to use a variable to control a widget.
for example, I would like to do this:

```
self.ui.label1.setText('hello')
```

but using a variable, like a string, let's say:

```
string = 'label1'
self.ui.string.setText('hello')  #this obviously doesn't work. ui doesn't recognize a string object.
```

Does any solution exist to this problem?
Thanks all!

Comment: Are you asking how you can declare a new `Widget` using a string type variable as the identifyer? If so, you could use `setattr(self.ui, string, QLabel('hello'))` for example.

Comment: the label already exists. i have label1 already in there as well as many others, but I need to control it,for example: setText setVisible etc  by using a string , coming from a function. The function returns 'label1' as an output, then I need to use that output 'label1' to do stuff with my label1 widget... I hope its clear ! thx a lot!

Comment: if the function returns 'label2' , then I want the program to use label2 instead

Comment: of course i could use something easy like if string == 'label1': and then do the stuff with label1 , then repeat for label2 and so on, but there are more than 400 labels in there, so it would be much better to use that string directly, I dont know if thats possible.

Answer (score 1):

I guess there are many ways of accomplishing of what I understand you would like to to. Here are two:

**Storing the labels in a dictionary**

```
labels = {
    'label1': self.ui.label1,
    'label2': self.ui.label2,
...
}


...

label = 'label1'

labels[label].setText('hello')
```

**Using getattr()**

```
...

label = 'label1'

getattr(self.ui, label).setText('hello')
```

This only works if the labels are attributes of `self.ui`